# prove that if $U\neq\mathbb{A}^n$ and $B_{(a,\epsilon)}\subseteq U$, then $U$ is not an affine algebraic set.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Without using hilbert's nullstellensatz prove that:

i) $B_{(0,\epsilon)}$ it's not an affine algebraic set.

(Where $B_{(a,b)}$ is the open disk with center $a$ and radius $b$)

I prove this using the fact that if $V(P)=B_{(0,\epsilon)}$ then $P(x_1,0,...,0)\in\textit k[x_1]$ is zero iff $x_1\in [-\epsilon,\epsilon]$, wich is absurd because the only proper affine algebraic sets are finite.

ii) $\mathbb I(B_{(0,\epsilon)})$?

I know that $\mathbb I(B_{(0,\epsilon)})=\mathbb I(A^n)$, but how can I prove it?

iii) If $U\neq\mathbb{A}^n$, $a\in\mathbb A^n$ and $B_{(a,\epsilon)}\subseteq U$, then $U$ is not an affine algebraic set.

Answer (score 2):

Just apply the same idea from part (i).  If you have a polynomial vanishing on $B_{0, \varepsilon}$, then its restriction to any line is a univariate polynomial vanishing on the interval $(-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)$.  Since a nonzero univariate polynomial can only vanish at finitely many points, its restriction to any line is zero.  Then use that to establish that the polynomial itself is zero.  So $I(B_{0, \varepsilon}) = (0)$.  Finally, any polynomial vanishing on a set *containing* $B_{0, \varepsilon}$ is zero for the same reason, so the closure of such a set is all of $\mathbb{A}^n$.  But an affine algebraic set is closed by definition, hence equal to its closure.